# Automorphism of Labeled Number Line

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, automorphism-group

[image: Labeled graph]

This is the graph I am working with and the edge labelings are given by $l(\{2n, 2n + 1\}) = a$ and $l(\{2n + 1, 2n + 2\}) = b$.

The question I'm working on guides us through to a description of the automorphism group of this graph. I so far have the isomorphisms (defined on the vertices) given by $\mu (n) = 1-n$ and $\nu (n) = n+2$. And I have that $\nu^k (n) = n + 2k$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. I have also shown that $\nu^{-m}(\{2m, 2m+1\}) = \{0,1\}$ for all $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. We are told that $\phi$ is an element of Aut($\Gamma$).

Now, the part I am confused about is as follows.

Define $\theta = \nu^{-m} \circ \phi$, where $\phi$ is as above, so $\theta (\{0,1\}) = \{0,1\}$. Show that either $\theta = \text{Id}_{\Gamma}$ or $\mu \circ \theta = \text{Id}_{\Gamma}$. Use this to show that either $\phi = \nu^m$ or $\phi = \nu^m \circ \mu$. Thus, show that $\text{Aut}(\Gamma) = \{\nu^m, \nu^m\mu : m \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ and that no two elements
of the latter set are equal.

I honestly don't know how to tackle this at all, everything I try seems to just go in circles and I don't think putting my workings here would help. I feel like I don't have enough information about $\phi$, but I must do... I think maybe I'm just struggling to comprehend what the question is asking?

I have basic graphs knowledge (this is the first and only question I've done involving edge labeling and automorphisms), and fundamental group theory knowledge.

Comment: First step: what useful thing can you say must be true about _either_ $\theta$ _or_ $\mu\circ\theta$?

Comment: $\theta (\{0,1\}) = \{0,1\}$ is key. This means there are only two possibilities for how $\theta$ acts on 0 and on 1. Can you say what they are?

Comment: Oh, and I guess before going beyond it, is it clear to you why $\theta (\{0,1\}) = \{0,1\}$? That's nothing deep, just a bit of calculation, but you should be clear about it first.

Comment: @JonathanZ Yes it's clear to me why $\theta(\{0,1\}) = \{0,1\}$. But, I'm unsure what you meant by there being two possibilities for how $\theta$ acts on 0 and 1?

Comment: Well, let's start with: What are the possible values for $\theta (0)$?

Comment: Wait, does $\{0,1\}$ mean an edge or a set containing two vertices to you?

Comment: @JonathanZ I believe in the notation my course is using it means an edge

Comment: @JonathanZ I don't know what $\phi(0)$ would be, maybe I don't understand automorphisms very well, my guess is just an arbitrary $2n$? In which case $\theta(0) = \nu^{-m} (2n)$ and if $m=n$ then $\theta(0) = 0$ and if $m \neq n$ then $\theta(0) = 2n - 2m$? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Y'know, that's my bad. I thought there could be more than one edge between two vertices, but I was wrong. Your notation seems standard.

Comment: First, don't get $\theta$ and $\phi$ confused. Second: okay, a graph automorphism takes vertices to vertices and edges to edges, and veertices of edges get mapped to vertices of edge that the original edge was mapped to. Are you good on that?

Comment: And you've shown that $\theta$ maps the edge $\{0,1\}$ to the edge $\{0,1\}$. So what can $\theta$ the vertex $0$ to?

Comment: @JonathanZ Yes, e.g. $\mu$ and $\nu$ are automorphisms of $\Gamma$, right? They just shift or reflect the graph but preserve the edges. $\theta$ sends the vertex $0$ to the vertex $0$? This is obvious to me and I don't see how it helps with the question, can it also send $0$ to $1$ because $\{0,1\}$ is unordered?

Comment: The idea is to take $m = n$ - it seems like that might not be clear to you. This strategy is what I learned as a "nail-it-to-the-wall proof". You start by identifying a bunch of automorphisms (the group generated by $\nu$ and $\mu$). You then show this is all of the automorphisms by taking an arbitrary automorphism $\phi$, and composing with $\nu$ and $\mu$ to "nail down" more and more of its properties. Eventually you've nailed down so much that $\phi$ must be Id, and then you're done. A similar strategy can be used to prove eg "an isometry of $\Bbb R^2$ that fixes $0$ must be linear".

Comment: So I would set up the main steps as 1: show that given an arbitrary automorphism $\phi$, you can compose with $\mu$ and $\nu$ to obtain an automorphism $\psi$ such that $\psi(0) = 0$ and $\psi(1) = 1$. Then 2: show that if $\psi$ is an automorphism such that $\psi(0) = 0$ and $\psi(1) = 1$, then $\psi$ must be the identity.

Comment: Yes, it can also send $0$ to $1$. Those are the (only) two possibilities, And (foreshadowing!) it's why you'll end up with the two possibilities $\phi = \nu^m \circ \mu$, or $\phi = \nu^m$. But I hope you're getting @IzaakvanDongen's comments - he's explaining the top-level strategy very clearly and explicitly.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Thank you - that makes sense. Just one thing to clear in my mind, by m=n do you mean that $\theta(0) = \nu^0 \circ \phi (0)$ and $\theta(1) = \nu^1 \circ \phi (1)$ etc? I.e., the superscript on $\nu$ should match the vertex I am acting on? Or something else? I think this is a key thing I'm getting stuck with here

Comment: Sorry, that was unclear - I intended to respond to your comment about $\theta(0) = 2n - 2m$, but that was a little confused in the first place. So: you're given an autom. $\phi$. It's now up to you to pick a clever number $m$ and use $\nu^{-m}$ to get an automorphism that's "closer" to the identity. This number $m$ can't really depend on a vertex - it depends on the whole automorphism $\phi$ in one go. As the qn says, you should show that there is an $m$ such that $\nu^{-m} \phi$ fixes the edge $\{0, 1\}$. PS: if you work out all the details, feel free to post in an answer below (if you like)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've got, and I think it makes sense...

There are two cases for $\theta$.
\begin{equation}
\text{Case 1: }\theta (0) = 0 \text{, and } \theta(1) = 1 \\
\text{Case 2: }\theta(0)=1 \text{, and } \theta(1) = 0
\end{equation}

Given case 1, I claim that $\theta = \text{Id}_{\Gamma}$.

As $\theta$ is an isomorphism, case 1 forces $n \mapsto n$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$. To illustrate, consider where $\theta$ sends $2$. It cannot be that $2 \mapsto 0$ nor $2 \mapsto 1$ as then $\theta$ would not be injective. Additionally, as $\theta$ is an isomorphism, the vertex $2$ must be incident to the vertex $1$ in the image of $\theta$. Thus, we must have $2 \mapsto 2$, and similarly for the vertex $-1$ and so on. Therefore, $\theta = \text{Id}_{\Gamma}$.

Given case 2, I claim that $\mu \circ \theta = \text{Id}_{\Gamma}$.

Notice that, $\mu(\theta(1)) = 1$ and $\mu(\theta(0)) = 0$. And so, the argument above applies in this case to $\mu \circ \theta$, i.e., $\mu \circ \theta = \text{Id}_{\Gamma}$.